# Print specific lines using sed from a grep output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm practicing following tutorials, my goal is searching only on users, and printing into a txt file, so I have the next command so far.

```bash
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | grep -n $search_param
```

Here I get an output of all the lines that match the criteria of $search_param. But now I wanna use sed to display it, so I can replace the ":" delimiters with for example "\t" in sed exp. After that I just make a file, but my trouble is filtering only using the first column with grep, and proceed to show all the information it has on that desired line.

I tried piping it directly into sed but it doesn't seem to work as it will technically seed the line numbers, not the specific lines on /etc/passwd.

Comment: The tutorial you have has an [UUOC](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119)

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the content of `$search_param`?

Comment: @Jetchisel I'm not following a specific tutorial, I just search stuff as I need this for a not directly related college stuff, never got hands into bash scripting nor unix commands but they request a script on it, so I was just doing what I could with what I had time to learn. What is the correct way of doing such thing?

Comment: @GauravPathak The content of $search_param is an user name. The output will be all the content of the lines that matches the user, but it has to be from the first column only, so it shouldn't search for matching lines which contains the search parameter, but the lines that contains the search parameter in the first "column", example:

I have two lines on any file in this case /etc/passwd
admin:bin:test
bin:admin:hello
If `$search_param` is `bin` for example, it will output to `file.txt` all lines that match (only on 1st column).
bin:admin:hello

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do newline on stackoverflow.

Comment: `search_param=agusteando; awk -F':' -v var="$search_param" '$1==var{print NR, "\t",  $1}' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat`-to-`awk`-to-`grep`-to-`sed` is a *painful* antipattern. Just use `awk`.

```
awk -F: -v key="$search_param" '$1~key { print $1 "\t" $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

You could also space-pad, truncate, and even right-align. `printf` is pretty flexible.

```
awk -F: -v key="$search_param" '$1~key{printf "%+20.20s\t%+40.40s\n", $1, $5}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: It is so painful because *each step* is awkward.  `cat`-to-`awk` is always unnecessary, as `awk` alone can serve.  `awk`-to-`grep` can also be replaced by just `awk`, though this one is the most forgivable, as there may be a clarity or separation-of-concerns advantage to be gained here.  `grep`-to-`sed`, however, is almost as bad as `cat`-to-`awk`, being completely replacable by `sed` alone.